# Find net working days and also remove exception dates in the current month

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently working on a project that involves extracting start and end dates for specific activities to excel (from project).

From here i want to split the working days out over each month depending on how many working days are between the two dates over the specific months those dates fall on. For example if between the 1/08/2022 and 3/09/2022 with holidays between 1/08/2022 and 3/08/2022 there will be 20 days in august and 2 networkdays in September after taking out the holidays. Id like to do this fast and for a large scale of tasks.

I also want to remove the exception days (Or holidays) from the working days and then take the total. I do this manually on a regular basis and would be eager to get a vba function to do this automatically after inputting the data.

[image]

If this isnt possible does somebody have a macro to convert a list of multiple start and end dates into a list of individual dates? this would make it easy to create a holiday exception list.

Brax: I've uploaded the excel file to the easy upload link below. Have a look.

The first set july-june divides the start and end date over the months. The next set july to june converts this to working days. I now need to just be able to remove exclusion periods out of the code. I get this works for single dates using the (although i need it to work for a date range (eg: 15/07/2022 to 20/07/2022.

(Just an FYI i have a dynamic calendar for financial year i am using)

Comment: brax give me a min ill send you all the codes for the breakup of months so far

Comment: Please do not include links to external files in your question.

Comment: how do you wsant me to poresent 50 lines of code then

Answer (score 1):

It is a built in function in Excel, able to do what you want. But if the network days are the same for any country, most holidays are specific to every country...

1. Please, choose a range (on any sheet, hidden or not) where to write holiday days for your country. Select the specific range and write in `Name Box` (to the left side of formula bar) a name, let us say, "rngHolidays" and **press Enter**. From now on the respective range can be used as `Range("rngHolidays").
2. You can use the next formula to return what you need **in a cell**"
   `=NETWORKDAYS(C2,D2,rngHolidays)`
   Where in C2 should be the starting `Date` and in D2 ending `Date`.
3. If you really want it in VBA you can use the next function:

```
Function netwkDays(rngStart As Range, rngEnd As Range, rngH As Range) As Long
    netwkDays = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(rngStart, rngEnd, rngH)
End Function
```

Then, use it in the next way:

```
Sub testnetwkDays()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rngH As Range
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  
  Debug.Print netwkDays(sh.Range("C2"), sh.Range("D2"), Range("rngHolidays"))
End Sub
```

Instead of returning in `Immediate Window` you may do it in a cell. I mean:

```
 sh.Range("B2").Value = netwkDays(sh.Range("C2"), sh.Range("D2"), Range("rngHolidays"))
```

Comment: thanks for your help, what if my holidays, as i showed in the image have a start and end date? i need all dates between the start and end date to be holidays?

Comment: @Bailey Angeloski I am afraid I cannot get you. The above solution uses a start Date and a end Date to extract work days. To supplementary **do not count holiday** they (holiday days) should be place in a range (being specific to your country, they cannot be known by me or by the function...). What do you mean by "I need all dates between the start and end date to be holiday"? **In `rngHolidays` you must place the holidays you want to except from counting**! When you say "have a start and end date" don't you refer only to the date you show? This is that **holiday exception list** you mentioned

Comment: Im exporting a excpetions list from ms project and it comes in the form of start and end date. That means everything between that start and end date is considered a holiday for what i am trying to do. I need a code that views all the dates between the start and end date and counts them as holidays. What you have given me takes single dates in the rngH or under a single range. Do you get what i am saying now? Look at the screenhshot of my exception list. The start and end dates on the exception list i need to be my holidays.

Comment: @Bailey Angeloski What do you mean by "exception days (Or holidays)"? In the normal world they cannot be more than two consecutive... So, you do not care about the national holidays, you need to except some periods (vacation, maintenance etc.) when the company is closed? I can adapt the code to build such a range and use it, but I would like to understand what is it about. Your question is not clear from this point of view. Supposing that we forget about national 'holidays' and except a Dates interval, to create a new sheet, hide it, create there the necessary range and use it, will  it be OK?

Comment: @Bailey Angeloski I am still confused... If 'Start Date' and 'End Date' are the days to be excepted, **which to be the start and end interval for which the function to calculate the workdays**? Where from to be extracted? Should the calculations be done **for each month, only excluding the interval you are talking about**? Not caring about the national holidays?

Comment: @Bailey Angeloski If my above supposition is correct, your picture is not good enough, not showing column and rows headers. If you want the code returning the networkdays for each month I must know where to place the returned values. I mean, something as: The months name will be placed on the first row, starting from column E:E and rows to be processed are from the third to seventh, taking the exceptions interval from columns  C:D...

Comment: ill post the solution i have come up with.

Comment: my "holidays" i need are everything between a start and end date. they need to be deducted from the net work days

Comment: my "holidays" i need are everything between a start and end date. they need to be deducted from the net work days eg: =NETWORKDAYS(C2,D2,rngHolidays)

c2 = 1/1/2022
d2 = 1/6/2022
rngholiday( Start date = 1/2/2022 to end date = 28/2/2022

Comment: @Bailey Angeloski This is what I deduced after our discussion and I was waiting for confirmation. I also asked about a "convenient" way of doing, I asked about headers etc.. But if you have the solution, I wish you succes in implementing it!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the help from the below links
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=76BRqJHH4Mk

Comment: this doesnt help. at all thanks. I know how to get work days already using the workdays/net work days forumla. Can you please re-read what i actually asked and am trying to solve.

Comment: Combine it with EOMONTH and EDATE and you should get there

Comment: Please do not answer questions with just links to external sites like youtube.